# Adding values in two pandas Series based on index

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 Series, m and n:

```
>>> m = pd.Series([5,2,7,2], index=[0,1,2,3])
>>> m
    0    5
    1    2
    2    7
    3    2

>>> n = pd.Series([8,3], index=[0,2])
>>> n
    0    8
    2    3
```

I want to combine the values in the series based on the index values of both Series. The result of this combination would result in z:

```
>>> z
    0    13
    1     2
    2    10
    3     2
```

The answer is probably simple, but I haven't been able to find it so far. What would be the best way to do this? Thank you

Comment: `print (m.add(n, fill_value=0))`

Comment: I cannot find it, @Wen

Comment: @jezrael aha, it is hard to find it out : -) , since the question is not named properly  :-)

Comment: @Wen I'm semi new to SO, still learning. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @MapleSyrup yep , I mean the question I linked is not named properly , not yours :-) , happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
In [274]: m.add(n, fill_value=0)
Out[274]:
0    13.0
1     2.0
2    10.0
3     2.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you